# How not to select the last table data via clicking the table row using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem regarding adding a class of **(selected to the table row, except the last table data)**

First, via clicking edit button the modal will appear and the response will be appended to the table.

Now I want to achieve, If I click the table row I want to highlight it except the last child of table data. I have here my codes and my sample output, I will show you guys.

This is my table appended already, now I select the first table row, But the problem was, via clicking the table row, I want not to highlight the last child because the last child has other purposes of function.

[image: Output]

**This is my append function to put the response in the table.**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('button#chain_editBtn').click(function(){

        $('#EditchainingBuilderModal').modal('show');
        $("button#show_nounModalChain").attr('disabled', true);

        var get_chain_id = $(this).val();
        $('.edit_hidden_noun_id').val(get_chain_id);

        $.ajax({
            url:'/get_chain_data',
            type:'get',
            data:{get_chain_data_id: get_chain_id},
            success:function(response){

              var get_chain_name = response[0].get_chain_name[0].chain_name;
              var menu_builder_properties_id = response[0].get_chain_name[0].menu_builder_properties_id;

              $('.edit_hidden_noun_id').val(menu_builder_properties_id);
              $('.edit_noun_build_item').text(get_chain_name);


               var get_chain_data = response[0].get_chain_data;


               $.each(get_chain_data, function (index, el) {

                var stringify = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(el));

                var menu_cat_price = stringify['menu_cat_price'];
                var Qty = stringify['Qty'];
                var Price = stringify['Price'];
                var Condiments = stringify['Condiments'];
                var menu_builder_details_id = stringify['menu_builder_details_id'];
                var condiments_section_id = stringify['condiments_section_id'];


                // $('#edit_chainingBuild').append("<tr class='clickable-row'><td>" + Qty + "</td><td class='clickable-row-condiments'>" + Condiments + "</td><td>" + Price + "</td><td style='display:none;' data-attribute-chain-id="+menu_builder_details_id +" class='data-attribute-chain-id'>"+menu_builder_details_id+"</td></tr>");
                $('#edit_chainingBuild').append("<tr class='clickable-row'><td class='clickable-row-condiments'>" + Condiments + "</td><td>" + Price + "</td><td style='display:none;' data-attribute-condiments-section-id="+condiments_section_id+" data-attribute-chain-id="+menu_builder_details_id +" class='data-attribute-chain-id'>"+menu_builder_details_id+"</td><td><button>X</button></td></tr>");

              })

            },
            error:function(){
              console.log(response);
            }
        })




  })
})
```

**Now I have my codes for on click function to highlight the table row.**

```
$('#edit_chainingBuild').on('click','tr.clickable-row','td:not(:last-child)',function () {

    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

My Html Table Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EditchainingBuilderModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg role="document" style="float:right; height:700px; width:490px; ">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header" style="background: linear-gradient(-30deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;">
            <h5 class="modal-title edit_noun_build_item" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="color:white;"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" id="closeBuildChainUpdate" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="header" style="text-align: center;">
                    <br>
                    <h3 style="color:#007BFF;">Build Your Chain Button</h3> 
                    <label>This button will be served as customers menu.</label><br>
                    <i class="fab fa-creative-commons-remix" style="font-size:70px;"></i>
                    <br><br>

                    <input type="hidden" value="" class="edit_hidden_noun_id" name="">
                    <table class="table table-hover" id="edit_chainingBuild">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="font-size: 15px;">
                                <!-- <th scope="col">Qty</th> -->
                                <th scope="col">Condiments</th>
                                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody style="font-size:14px;">                 

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="edit_build_success_insert btn btn-primary">Build Done</button>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your selector is incorrect`$('#edit_chainingBuild').on('click','tr.clickable-row td:not(:last-child)',function () {
});`

Comment: Hi @Satpal I already use that, only the first table data is highlighting

Comment: Hi @DevGe, can you paste your html and jquery code

Comment: Sure I will post as everyone request

Comment: I already update my post

Comment: perhaps on your first append, add a unique identifier to these cells. Then on your click function click these unique IDs.

Comment: thank you devs for helping me

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into your question. Instead, use the Answer box to answer your own question. Be sure to upvote any answers that helped you.

Comment: sure thank you for the help heretic.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#edit_chainingBuild').on('click',function () {
    $(this).closest('tr.clickable-row').find('td:not(:last-child)').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Hi @DevGe, i don't see edit_chainingBuild id your html code

Comment: You can answer your own question @DevGe

Comment: Thanks @tibs for the info

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem

```
 $('#edit_chainingBuild').on('click','tr.clickable-row',function () {
          $(this).closest('tr.clickable-row').find('td:not(:last-child)').addClass('selected');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way you could do It. Hope It helps.

```js
$('td').click((event) => {
  const parentRow = $(event.target).parent();
  parentRow.addClass('selected');
  $('tr').not(parentRow).removeClass('selected');
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

tr {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Call 1</td>
          <td>Call 1</td>
          <td>Call 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call 1</td>
          <td>Call 1</td>
          <td>Call 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Call 1</td>
          <td>Call 1</td>
          <td>Call 1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```